# How to convert UTC time field into JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, time, data-conversion

I want to convert the following object into `JSON` but I'm unable to do that because I'm getting the following error:

```py
TypeError: can not serialize 'datetime.datetime' object on "create_time":notification_object.create_time
```

I'm sending back to the server the following object by converting it into `JSON`:

```py
notification = {
    "id": notification_object.id,
    "sender": notification_object.sender,
    "receiver": notification_object.receiver,
    "message": notification_object.message,
    "create_time":notification_object.create_time,
}
```

I have tried to convert time into a string but that is returning:

```
2021-12-27 10:11:46.395138+00:00
```

and I want it to be formatted as:

```
2021-12-27T10:16:20.611423Z
```

Comment: `datetime` objects have a `toisoformat()` method. Did you try it?

Comment: I don't know about this. How to use it ?

Comment: `notification_object.create_time.isoformat()`

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. We have a `fromisoformat()`.

Comment: I have got this `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'toisoformat'`

Comment: The right method is the one Ersain just mentioned.

Comment: Now i have got `TypeError: fromisoformat() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Comment: The right method is [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), as pointed by Ersain. Check the document I linked.